# TypeScript erroring "Object is possibly 'undefined'."

Tags: typescript

I am working on a bot for Discord V13 in TypeScript. The problem is on line 17/18 (i have a note where the error is), i am getting an error saying "Object is possibly 'undefined'". I can't seem to find the issue as i am pretty new to JavaScript/TypeScript. I am hoping someone will be able to help me. Thanks.

```
import Discord, { Intents } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ] 
})

const Prefix = "!"

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot has initialized.")
})

Client.on("messageCreate", (Message) => {
    if(!Message.content.startsWith(Prefix) || Message.author.bot) return;

    const Args = Message.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const Command = Args.shift().toLowerCase() // This is 'undefined'

    switch (Command) {
        case "ping":
            Message.reply("pong")
            break;
    }
})

Client.login("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could fix this by adding [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or check if it's undefined first:**

```
Args?.shift()?.toLowerCase()
```

**OR**

```
Args.shift() && Args.shift().toLowerCase()
```